# Why are beit din-coerced gittin generally kosher

Tags: halacha, beit-din-court, divorce, legal-documents, even-haezer

The Passuk in the Torah outlining the rule for divorce is that if a husband loses favor in his wife. My question is, why in Halacha do most poskim rule that prenuptial agreements are fine and gittin after that are fine if the reason for the husband giving the get has nothing to do with the wife but because of external pressure (in this case from the beit din)?

Comment: Your question is very unclear and based on a number of unbased assumptions.

Comment: A decision from a bes din is the halacha from the Torah and  the nature of every Jew is to want to keep the Torah.